# Submitting jobs using qsub in matlab r2012a

Tags: matlab, qsub, parfor

I am running a code which includes a loop where I am splitting my task and sending it using **qsub** as different jobs. For eg I am calling:

```
function searchweights()
    startup
    distrJobs('UseMAR',false);
    distrJobs('UseMAR',true);
  end;
  function distrJobs(varargin)
    fprintf('entered distrJobs');
    UseMAR = false;
    w = {[0,3.^(-9:0)],[0,2.^(-7:1)]}; % grids
    for i = 1:2:numel(varargin)
      if strcmp(varargin{i},'wgrid'), w = varargin{i+1}; end
      if strcmp(varargin{i},'UseMAR'), UseMAR = varargin{i+1}; end
    end
    fprintf(' get cross validation accuracy for each grid point');
    [w1,w2] = ndgrid(w{1},w{2});
    n = numel(w1);
    for i = 1%:n
    command = sprintf('qsub  optionFile "crossvalid([%f,%f],''Xpred.mat'',''/data5/natraj/SWeight/SWeight_%d_%d.mat'',%d)"', w1(i), w2(i), UseMAR, i, UseMAR) 
    system(command);
    end;
  end;
```

and my crossvalid function goes like:

```
  function crossvalid(w,infile,outfile, UseMAR)
            startup
            load(infile);
            [A,R] = sbu.ClothParser.cross_validation(X, 'weights',[w(1),w(2)], 'UseMAR', UseMAR);
            save( outfile, 'A', 'R');
          end;
```

But after I run my searchweights function, the qsub command doesn't seem to run at all i.e it doesn't go into the "crossvalid" function. It gives this error in the error file: /data5/natraj/matlab2012a/bin/matlab: No match.

*(/data5/natraj/matlab2012a/bin/matlab is my matlab executable)

I am not getting what is really causing this error and how can I rule this out?

The operating system is Linux.

EDIT: The problem seems to be with qsub. When I run the same for loop using parfor, it is running.

Comment: do you have qsub in your path? `which qsub`. You'll have to make sure the client commands are setup on the machine where you are submitting the matlab job from.

Comment: I think I should close this problem. The problem was with passing the arguments. I was passing too many arguments in crossvalid. I don't know why but reducing the number of arguments worked.